# Python, virtualenv: telling IDE to run the debug session in virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv

My project's running fine in virtualenv. Unfortunately, I can't yet run it via my IDE (Eric) because of the import troubles. It stands to reason, as I never told the IDE anything about virtualenv.

I know the drill (**$ source project/bin/activate** etc.), but lack general understanding. What constitutes "running inside virtualenv"? What IDE options might be relevant?

Comment: You have to set your paths correctly. I don't know `Eric`, but there has to be some sort of project related settings where you configure the interpreter and search paths.

Comment: My point exactly. What paths? I don't know anything about the touches that virtualenv adds to the universe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know it is possible to run your script/project using your virtualenv simply by calling */path/to/your/venv/python your_script.py*. To install new packages in your venv for example, you would run */path/to/your/venv/pip install some_package*.

I guess the main advantage of "runnnig inside virtualenv" would be not being concerned about having to inform the location of python packages/executable everytime you want to run some script. But I lack general understanding too.

I usually install a virtualenv with the *--no-site-packages* option in order to have a "clean" installation of python.

--- EDIT ---

The second answer of [this](http://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/2nh1x3/why_o_why_activate_virtualenv/) discussion has a nice explanation.

Comment: **/home/alexey/spaces/python/py-procr/procr/bin/python** Interpreter for the debug client (Eric) works. I have to grok it. (Python prefix to google?)

Comment: I didn't get it when you said "Python prefix to google?". I'm happy you made it work :)

Answer (score 2):

I think the only required setting to run or debug code is path to python interpreter.
Relevant IDE options could be `SDK` or `Interpreter` settings.

Note that you should run not default python (eg. `/usr/bin/python`) but python binary in your virtual environment (eg `/path/to/virtualenv/bin/python`)

Also there are some environment variables set by `activate`, but i think they aren't needed when you point to virtualenv python binary directly.

So, again, what `activate` does is only environment variables setup: at least, it modifies system `$PATH` in a way that `python` and `pip` commands points to executable files under `path/to/virtaulenv/bin` directiry.

Answer (score 0):

Simply look at the `project/bin/activate`, everything you need is there to set up the appropriate search.

Usually the most important path is the `PYTHONPATH` which should point to the site-packages.